# UMVUE for $\theta$ of uniform distribution $\left[ \theta,\theta+1\right]$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification

Consider $X_{1} \dots X_{n}$ sample from $U[\theta, \theta +1]$.

Let's consider $f_{\theta} = \operatorname{1}(\theta \le X_{(1)} \le X_{(n)} \le \theta +1)$. Now we may say that there is two sufficient estimates.

First question what estimate we should take. 
$X_{(1)}$ or $X_{(n)}$?

Now let's take the former one. We need to consider $\int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} f(x) n(1+\theta -x)^{n-1} $, easy to see that is completeness estimate.

But the same idea about $X_{(n)}$. But we know that there is exist only one UMVUE.

What should we do here ?

Comment: @Raptor added , thanks

Comment: UMVUE of $\theta$ does not exist here. There is a proof on page 330-331 of *Introduction to the Theory of Statistics* by Mood-Graybill-Boes (third edition).

Comment: Clearly, a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is $T=(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$. And there does exist an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ based on $T$, namely $\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}-1}{2}$. But you would probably find that $T$ is not complete here. 

// You could appeal to the theorem which states that a necessary and sufficient condition for an unbiased estimator of some parametric function to be the UMVUE is that it must be uncorrelated with every unbiased estimator of zero. And try to find a contradiction.

Comment: @StubbornAtom there talking about that there is no estimators with zero variance for all $\theta$ , but why this is true? When it should be zero a.e.?